# Open Cart 2 Coupon Multiple

Tags: opencart2.x

I have been trying to figure out a way to do the following :

**Example,**

You Order the same 5 Chickens at £20 each and you apply a £5 off coupon for the product.
Instead of £95.00, the price should be £75.

Is this at all possible, I have been digging through the cart.php for hours I cant seem to find a way.

Comment: What version of OpenCart are you using?

Comment: I have updated the question to make more sense.

Comment: Please, use correct tag in the future, i.e. `opencart2.x`. Tag `opencart` is now supposed to be used for OC versions prior to OC 2.0.

Comment: Is your question only a general - finding whether it is possible or are you asking how to implement this?

Comment: Both, I cant seem to find anything to come close to a solution on the internet.